# Integration of CISCO router with C#

Tags: c#

```
public class Telnet
    {
        private IPEndPoint iep;
        private string address;
        private int port;
        private int timeout;
        private Socket s;
        Byte[] m_byBuff = new Byte[32767];
        private string strWorkingData = "";                 // Holds everything received from the server since our last processing
        private string strFullLog = "";
    public Telnet(string Address, int Port, int CommandTimeout)
    {
        address = Address;
        port = Port;
        timeout = CommandTimeout;
    }


    private void OnRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get The connection socket from the callback
        Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Get The data , if any
        int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive(ar);

        if (nBytesRec > 0)
        {
            // Decode the received data
            string sRecieved = CleanDisplay(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_byBuff, 0, nBytesRec));

            // Write out the data
            if (sRecieved.IndexOf("[c") != -1) Negotiate(1);
            if (sRecieved.IndexOf("[6n") != -1) Negotiate(2);

            // Console.WriteLine(sRecieved);
            strWorkingData += sRecieved;
            strFullLog += sRecieved;

            // Launch another callback to listen for data
            AsyncCallback recieveData = new AsyncCallback(OnRecievedData);
            sock.BeginReceive(m_byBuff, 0, m_byBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None, recieveData, sock);

        }
        else
        {
            // If no data was recieved then the connection is probably dead
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected", sock.RemoteEndPoint);
            sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close();
            //Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void DoSend(string strText)
    {
        try
        {
            Byte[] smk = new Byte[strText.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < strText.Length; i++)
            {
                Byte ss = Convert.ToByte(strText[i]);
                smk[i] = ss;
            }

            s.Send(smk, 0, smk.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ers)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ers.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show("ERROR IN RESPOND OPTIONS");
        }
    }

    private void Negotiate(int WhichPart)
    {
        StringBuilder x;
        string neg;
        if (WhichPart == 1)
        {
            x = new StringBuilder();
            x.Append((char)27);
            x.Append((char)91);
            x.Append((char)63);
            x.Append((char)49);
            x.Append((char)59);
            x.Append((char)50);
            x.Append((char)99);
            neg = x.ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            x = new StringBuilder();
            x.Append((char)27);
            x.Append((char)91);
            x.Append((char)50);
            x.Append((char)52);
            x.Append((char)59);
            x.Append((char)56);
            x.Append((char)48);
            x.Append((char)82);
            neg = x.ToString();
        }
        SendMessage(neg, true);
    }

    private string CleanDisplay(string input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects to the telnet server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True upon connection, False if connection fails</returns>
    public bool Connect()
    {
        IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.Resolve(address);
        string[] aliases = IPHost.Aliases;
        IPAddress[] addr = IPHost.AddressList;

        try
        {
            // Try a blocking connection to the server
            s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            iep = new IPEndPoint(addr[0], port);
            s.Connect(iep);

            // If the connect worked, setup a callback to start listening for incoming data
            AsyncCallback recieveData = new AsyncCallback(OnRecievedData);
            s.BeginReceive(m_byBuff, 0, m_byBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None, recieveData, s);

            // All is good
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Something failed
            return false;
        }

    }


    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (s.Connected) s.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for a specific string to be found in the stream from the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DataToWaitFor">The string to wait for</param>
    /// <returns>Always returns 0 once the string has been found</returns>
    public int WaitFor(string DataToWaitFor)
    {
        // Get the starting time
        long lngStart = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(this.timeout).Ticks;
        long lngCurTime = 0;

        while (strWorkingData.ToLower().IndexOf(DataToWaitFor.ToLower()) == -1)
        {
            // Timeout logic
            lngCurTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            if (lngCurTime > lngStart)
            {
                throw new Exception("Timed Out waiting for : " + DataToWaitFor);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        strWorkingData = "";
        return 0;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for one of several possible strings to be found in the stream from the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DataToWaitFor">A delimited list of strings to wait for</param>
    /// <param name="BreakCharacters">The character to break the delimited string with</param>
    /// <returns>The index (zero based) of the value in the delimited list which was matched</returns>
    public int WaitFor(string DataToWaitFor, string BreakCharacter)
    {
        // Get the starting time
        long lngStart = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(this.timeout).Ticks;
        long lngCurTime = 0;

        string[] Breaks = DataToWaitFor.Split(BreakCharacter.ToCharArray());
        int intReturn = -1;

        while (intReturn == -1)
        {
            // Timeout logic
            lngCurTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            if (lngCurTime > lngStart)
            {
                throw new Exception("Timed Out waiting for : " + DataToWaitFor);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < Breaks.Length; i++)
            {
                if (strWorkingData.ToLower().IndexOf(Breaks[i].ToLower()) != -1)
                {
                    intReturn = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return intReturn;

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a message to the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to send to the server</param>
    /// <param name="SuppressCarriageReturn">True if you do not want to end the message with a carriage return</param>
    public void SendMessage(string Message, bool SuppressCarriageReturn)
    {
        strFullLog += "\r\nSENDING DATA ====> " + Message.ToUpper() + "\r\n";
        // Console.WriteLine("SENDING DATA ====> " + Message.ToUpper());

        if (!SuppressCarriageReturn)
        {
            DoSend(Message + "\r");
        }
        else
        {
            DoSend(Message);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a message to the server, automatically appending a carriage return to it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to send to the server</param>
    public void SendMessage(string Message)
    {
        strFullLog += "\r\nSENDING DATA ====> " + Message.ToUpper() + "\r\n";
        // Console.WriteLine("SENDING DATA ====> " + Message.ToUpper());

        DoSend(Message + "\r");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for a specific string to be found in the stream from the server.
    /// Once that string is found, sends a message to the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WaitFor">The string to be found in the server stream</param>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to send to the server</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true once the string has been found, and the message has been sent</returns>
    public bool WaitAndSend(string WaitFor, string Message)
    {
        this.WaitFor(WaitFor);
        SendMessage(Message);
        return true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a message to the server, and waits until the designated
    /// response is received
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to send to the server</param>
    /// <param name="WaitFor">The response to wait for</param>
    /// <returns>True if the process was successful</returns>
    public int SendAndWait(string Message, string WaitFor)
    {
        SendMessage(Message);
        this.WaitFor(WaitFor);
        return 0;
    }

    public int SendAndWait(string Message, string WaitFor, string BreakCharacter)
    {
        SendMessage(Message);
        int t = this.WaitFor(WaitFor, BreakCharacter);
        return t;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A full log of session activity
    /// </summary>
    public string SessionLog
    {
        get
        {
            return strFullLog;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Clears all data in the session log
    /// </summary>
    public void ClearSessionLog()
    {
        strFullLog = "";
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Searches for two strings in the session log, and if both are found, returns
    /// all the data between them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="StartingString">The first string to find</param>
    /// <param name="EndingString">The second string to find</param>
    /// <param name="ReturnIfNotFound">The string to be returned if a match is not found</param>
    /// <returns>All the data between the end of the starting string and the beginning of the end string</returns>
    public string FindStringBetween(string StartingString, string EndingString, string ReturnIfNotFound)
    {
        int intStart;
        int intEnd;

        intStart = strFullLog.ToLower().IndexOf(StartingString.ToLower());
        if (intStart == -1)
        {
            return ReturnIfNotFound;
        }
        intStart += StartingString.Length;

        intEnd = strFullLog.ToLower().IndexOf(EndingString.ToLower(), intStart);

        if (intEnd == -1)
        {
            // The string was not found
            return ReturnIfNotFound;
        }

        // The string was found, let's clean it up and return it
        return strFullLog.Substring(intStart, intEnd - intStart).Trim();
    }


}
```

I need to connect Cisco router using Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) from a C# application and get the below details:

> CPU and Memory Utilization of Cisco router.

Below is the code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CiscoNoEnable cNE = new CiscoNoEnable();
            cNE.sHostName = "172.22.5.143";
            cNE.sUsername = "Eyespot@123";
            cNE.sPassword = "eyespot@123";
            cNE.getConfig();
        }
    }
    public class CiscoNoEnable
    {

        public string sHostName;
        public string sUsername;
        public string sPassword;

        private void Initialize_Components()
        {
            sHostName = "";
            sUsername = "";
            sPassword = "";
        }

        public CiscoNoEnable()
        {
            Initialize_Components();
        }
        public void getConfig()
        {

            this.sHostName = this.sHostName.Trim();
            this.sUsername = this.sUsername.Trim();
            this.sPassword = this.sPassword.Trim();

            RafiTEL.Telnet mST = new RafiTEL.Telnet(this.sHostName, 23, 8);

            if (mST.Connect() == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Error: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Timeout connecting to: " + this.sHostName);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    mST.WaitFor("Username:");
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }
                mST.SendMessage(this.sUsername);
                mST.WaitFor("Password:");
                mST.SendMessage(this.sPassword);
                mST.WaitFor("#");
                mST.SendMessage("term len 0");
                mST.WaitFor("#");
                mST.SendMessage("show run");
                mST.WaitFor("#");
                mST.SendMessage("exit");
                Console.Write(mST.FindStringBetween("bytes\r\n", "\r\n\r\n", "Error: Configuration not obtained"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries or references. Please add the `using` statements too.

Comment: using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

Comment: What is your actual problem? For anyone to help you will have to ask something specific.